# A/B test involving two distinct versions of a mobile application

Tags: android, firebase, mobile-application, ab-testing

I would like to share certain updates pertaining to the application interface and advertising scenarios (version 1.2.0 - not yet released). I intend to conduct an A/B test to evaluate and compare the performance of this update against the current application version available on the play store (version 1.1.0), with a focus on determining which version yields superior financial outcomes. Could you kindly assist me in setting up this test on Firebase?

Your assistance is greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Firebase does not allow A/B testing between two different versions of an application, especially when one version has already been released.